# In Xcode, make a button look like a text field or a textfield look like a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In Xcode (iOS), I have a screen with a combination of buttons and text fields.  However, they look different.  Is there a way that I can have a button look like a textfield? Or is there a way I can make a textfield act like a button (perform some action when pressed and don't bring up the keyboard)?

Thanks

Comment: I could not imagine why anyone would want to do this

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'm sure there is a better way, then this. Apple surely won't accept a misleading GUI like that.

Comment: Many people use grouped UITableViewCell with UITextField in it to create a similar style... All I can think of.

Comment: It's because buttons and text fields look slightly different and thus it is inconsistent across my page.  When someone presses a textfield I want a new page to pop up that will give them more room to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try one of these:

- place a transparent (custom with no image) button on top of the text field and attach the desired action to it
- show your view in the implementation of the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol method

Subclassing is also an option, but it will probably complicate your task too much.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to perform an action and do not bring up the keyboard when pressed on `UITextField` You can do it like this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // do here everything you want
    NSLog(@"Pressed on TextField!");

    [self.view endEditing:YES]; // Hide keyboard

    return NO;
}
```

This function will be called every time when pressed on textField.

** Don't forget to **delegate** `UITextField`.

Note: With this You will face the problem: if keyboard is shown it will not hide, so You need also add `-endEditing:YES`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom one of them ... or both

Exemple : create a class CustomTextField : UITextField

in this class use :

```
  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Play with style

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but nevertheless. I did this to make a UIButton look like a UITextField

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resolutionButton;
```

And in viewDidLoad:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[self.resolutionButton layer] setBorderColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6f alpha:0.6f].CGColor];
    self.resolutionButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.resolutionButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
}
```